# INSERT / UPDATE data using DBNull or null?

Tags: sql-server, null

When modifying data in a SQL Server database you can use either `System.DBNull.Value` or `null` to represent a `NULL` value. Both of these will work and will set the proper value to `NULL`.

My question is - **which of these is preferred, and why?** Are there certain cases where one should be used in place of the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [System.DBNull.Value != null](http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2004/04/12/system-dbnull-value-null/), and by testing this code:

```
var result = (System.DBNull.Value == null); // this is always false
```

We can see that the CLR doesn't treat them the same way. When retrieving data from a database we need to check for `DBNull.Value` and not a `null` reference.

Although it doesn't matter which we use to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` data, I would tend to stick with `DBNull.Value` for consistency through data access code.

There are a variety of other opinions in the question [C# Database Access: DBNull vs null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836/c-sharp-database-access-dbnull-vs-null)

Comment: your first part  isnt relevant to the question :) - Ive already ansered that my self in the Question Itself.` still , which of these is preferred, and why? ` (in inserting mode.) ?

Comment: It's relevant in that it sets up my position which is that **since it matters when reading** you should stay consistent and **use it when inserting or updating**.

Comment: I heard that there is a dependencefor RDBMS type..no ?

Comment: Your question is tagged for SQL Server where they are treated the same. I can't speak to other RDBMS connectors. I did notice that one of the answers on the related question seems to indicate that Oracle requires the use of `DBNull`.

Answer (score 0):

DBNull is representative of a variant and is not type-specific. In a general context, I would expect a performance hit anywhere you have a construct that expects a strongly-typed dataset and has to convert DBNull to a "typed-NULL".